# When doob martingale is continuous

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

Give a probability space $\left(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P\right)$ and a filtration $\left\{ \mathscr{F}_{t}:0\le t<\infty\right\} $ and a random variable $X$. Define the doob martingale $S_{t}=E\left[X|\mathscr{F}_{t}\right]$. Under what condition $\left\{ S_{t},\mathscr{F}_{t}:0\le t<\infty\right\}$  is a continuous martingale? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any thoughts on the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @saz If $\left\{ \mathscr{F}_{t}:0\le t<\infty\right\}$ satisifies the usual condition, then by the famous regularity theorem of submartingale (Theorem 1.3.13 in Karatzas/Shreve in the book "Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus"), $S$ has a RCLL modification. However, I still do not know how to get a continuous martingale.